# dynamically add textbox and dropdownbox when click on plus symbol in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

i need to add columns one by one in asp.net by click on plus symbol then  one textbox and dropdown will appear dynamically  and when click on minus that will disappear .

whenever user enter the data in textbox and dropdown and clickon plus symbol the that row will save in db and new empty textbox and dropdown will appear UI .this goes on.

How to acheive this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `jQuery`. I personally would do this using `jQuery` and `knockout.js` as seen in the following [Templating example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/templating.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that via server-side programming. Use `JavaScript` or `jQuery`.